# jquery on('click') handler for multiple elements referenced by vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

N.B. I'm aware that I add ids and combine these in a selector e.g. "#myDiv1,#myDiv2" so please refrain from suggesting this as it does not relate to my question.

Is there a way to 'chain' the vars below together in one on() declaration maybe as an array or something?

```
var myDiv1 = $('<div>Something here</div>');
var myDiv2 = $('<div>Something else here</div>');

myDiv1.on('click', function(){ doSomething();});
myDiv2.on('click', function(){ doSomething();});
```

I have a bunch of vars that I need to do some broad tracking of mouse events and it feels messy setting them up individually like the above example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You can pass an **array of DOM elements to the jQuery function**:

  ```
  $([
      myDiv1.get(0), 
      myDiv2.get(0)
  ]).on('click', function(){ doSomething();});
  ```

  [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R9XzV/)
- Another possible way is to use the **[`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method**:

  ```
  myDiv1.add(myDiv2).on('click', function(){ doSomething();});
  ```

  [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R9XzV/1/)
- Put them in an **array, loop through them** and attach the same handler. I made the example with ES5 `forEach`, but feel free to use a simple `for` loop or `$.each`.

  ```
  [cucc, gomb].forEach(function (el) {
      el.on('click', handler);
  });
  ```

  [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R9XzV/2/)
- If they have a common ancestor, put a common class on them and use **event delegation**. Depending on the number of your elements, this could be the best solution performance-wise, because you only have to attach one handler to the common ancestor.

  ```
  $('.ancestor').on('click', '.common', handler);
  ```

  [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R9XzV/3/)

Comment: Great thanks - will accept when in 5 mins - I used myDiv1[0] for brevity

Comment: @Rob Thinking through again, the last option seems to be the best, if it can be used.

Comment: I have handles to the items anyway as I need regular access to these DOM Nodes for a range of other functions within my plugins. Surely your last solution would not be as efficient as the direct approach in your original answer, I was under the impression broad-stroke selectors were fairly inefficient - and I'm looking for saving wherever I can find them as my plugin is doing a lot of work so the leaner the better (to the point where I'm actually timing everything to ensure that new bits of code don't kill my finely tuned beast!).

Comment: @rob Yep I get it. I mean *generally* the last solution is preferred. In your scenario, it might be not.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Kapa's answer. If you need to bind multiple elements to which have been added, prepended, appended, loaded with ajax or javascript.

**Loop through multiple classes and create bindings "for each" element**

```
var thisButton = '.this-button', //This element was added by js
    thatButton = '.that-button', //That element was added by ajax
    thesebuttons = [thisButton, thatButton];

    thesebuttons.forEach(function (button) {
        $(document).on('click touchend', button, function (e) {
        // 'e' or event, uncomment to prevent button's default event
        // e.preventDefault(); 

        // Now do your function stuff

        });
    });
```